# How to send email to all Wordpress users

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am trying to send all of my users an email for a custom event. For this, I have written the following code but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
//send mail to all users

$result= $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_email FROM $table_users"));

foreach($result as $email) {

      $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
      $headers.= "From:mysite<info@mysite.com>\r\n";
      $message = "<b>Dear! user</b>,<br/><br/> A new share is available to purchase 
                        for amount $".$sellamt."<br>this is an automated mail.pls  don't reply to this mail. ";
      $send=mail($email,"mysite:New share Available to Purchase!",$message,$headers);
}

header('Location: /offer_csuccess');  
exit();
```

Comment: Pro tips when posting here: as per the front page, please write your titles and paragraphs in sentence case like this, and Not In Title Case Like This (since the latter is harder to read). Please also refrain from txtspk (e.g. "pls", "thx") - that's just lazy, and they give new work to volunteer editors. Above all, make a good effort with your posts.

Answer (score 3):

Use [get_users](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) function to get all users depending on roles or any parameter you pass.

```
$users = get_users();

foreach( $users as $user ) {

    wp_mail( $user->user_email, "New Share Available to Purchase!", $message );
}
```

Also using WordPress you have advantage not to mention the headers every time. You just need to use [wp_mail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/). It really does sending email simpler.

Hope it help :)

Answer (score 0):

get all user function `get_users();`

```
$all_users = get_users();
foreach ($all_users as $user) {


      $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
      $headers.= "From:mysite<info@mysite.com>\r\n";
      $message = "<b>Dear! user</b>,<br/><br/> A new share is available to purchase 
                        for amount $".$sellamt."<br>this is an automated mail.pls  don't reply to this mail. ";
      $send=mail($user->user_email,"mysite:New share Available to Purchase!",$message,$headers);
}

 exit();
```